# RemoteLogging changed in gwt 2.6?

Tags: gwt

After upgrading to gwt 2.6 I'm getting this error on the server when using remote loggin:

```
com.google.gwt.logging.shared.RemoteLoggingService.logOnServer(java.util.logging.LogRecord)' threw an unexpected exception: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceUtil.logOnServer(Ljava/util/logging/LogRecord;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/core/server/StackTraceDeobfuscator;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`StackTraceDeobfuscator` has moved form `com.google.gwt.core.server.impl` to `com.google.gwt.core.server`. Make sure you use a 2.6.0 version of the `gwt-servlet.jar`.

Comment: That's what I did in the first place. I'm using Eclipse with GPE and changed to 2.6 and made sure to remove the old gwt-serlet.jar before. Or is it possible that the GPE distribution contains the wrong jar? It may be a good idea to add a version number to the jars to make it easier to find out which version is used.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever you change the GWT version, make sure you have deleted all the stubs that is auto generated by previous GWT version.

Delete all the selected files/folders as shown in below snapshot and clean the project and run the GWT compilation again. I hope this will solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: I've removed all the directories and even changed to GWT 2.6.1 but the error still persists. I've seen that all server files are also included in gwt-user.jar - is anyone using remote logging on app engine with gwt  2.6+ successfully?